# Can we know the space between text and the top of the UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, padding

With UILabels there seems to be a permanent border of emptiness around the text. Trying things like

```
label.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

doesn't do anything and the gap between the top of the text and the top of the label seems to be proportionate to the font size.

Is there a way to make the gap go away? Or is there a way to know how big the gap is?

Comment: use edgeinsets method for label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the gap value:

```
    CGSize labelSize=label.frame.size;
    CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    // Assuming that the text is centered inside the label
    CGFloat topGap = (labelSize.height-textSize.height)/2
```